# Считывание нескольких переменных из строк файла

Tags: python, файловый-ввод-вывод

Имеется текстовый файл с фиксированным количеством значений в каждой строке (по 3 штуки в каждой из 3 строк). Значения - вещественные цифры призвольной длинны. Каждой перменной нужно присвоить свое значение (всего получается 9 переменных).
Пример текстового документа:

```
0.12 0.334 3.12
1 5.34 94.2
12.4 32.3 653.04
```

Пытался решить через while, но запнулся на а)Выходе за range б)необходимости записи нескольких переменных:

```
p = ['']
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    for i in line:
        i = int(i)
        while line[i] != ' ':
            p.append(line[i])
            i += 1
        p1 = float(str(p))
print(p1)
```

Comment: Вы бы помещали полный код (нет части чтения из файла, например, нет объявления p). И "Каждой перменной нужно присвоить свое значение (всего получается 9 переменных)."- список не устроит? Нужно типа a?, b, c, и т.д.?

Comment: @Сергей код дополнил, список я использую здесь в качестве посредника. В итоге мне нужно a, b, c тд.

Comment: Я так понимая словарь тоже не устроит? Со своими уникальными ключами

Comment: @СергейШашко да, мне необходимы отдельные переменные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странноватая задача - 9 переменных.

```
    f=open('a.txt', 'r')
    p=[]
    with open("a.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            p.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
        a,b,c, d,e,f, g,h,i=(p[z][y] for z in range (3) for y in range (3))             
    print (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) #0.12 0.334 3.12 1.0 5.34 94.2 12.4 32.3 653.04
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: У меня работает, как в комментарии написал в последней строке. Да и с чего бы не работать ей. На какую строку ругается? Входной файл точно, как в задаче? Запускаете в чём? (IDLE? PyCharm?)

Comment: форматирование поехало. все работает

Comment: смотрите обновление. Теперь красивее сделал:-) И примите снова, если устраивает.